# Solr and schemaless

Tags: solr, cloudera

I'm using **Cloudera 5.4** with **Solr 4.10.2** and I would like to activate the schemaless.

I've edited the `solrconf.xml` with

```
<schemaFactory class="ManagedIndexSchemaFactory">
    <bool name="mutable">true</bool>
    <str name="managedSchemaResourceName">managed-schema</str>
</schemaFactory>
```

I don't know if I need something else for this version. I have read the Solr documentation (https://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Managed+Schema+Definition+in+SolrConfig)

When I try to index an document, I get an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrServer$RouteException: ERROR: [doc=5.417393032179468E7] unknown field 'campo1'

I have seen that there's an schema.xml.bak how the documentation says.

Do I need to do something else?

Comment: Can you try restarting your solr servers? Seems like a similar issue here, which was fixed by restarting. http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Updating-solrconfig-xml-with-zookeeper-amp-HDFS-td4169074.html

Comment: I tried to restarted many times. How it's managed by Cloudera Manager I'm not sure that it reads the right config files although it seems that it does.